# Javascript Leading Zero Function as Argument

Tags: javascript, leading-zero

Exist some way that javascript recognize the leading zero as argument (with the primitive value as number)? I have this code:

```js
    let noLeadinZero = (number) => { return number }

    console.log('noLeadinZero(00):', noLeadinZero(00)) // 0
    console.log('noLeadinZero(000):', noLeadinZero(000)) // 0
    console.log('noLeadinZero(0000):', noLeadinZero(0000)) // 0
```

Exist a way, beside the fact i can put the argument of the call of the function in string, for recognize the leading zeros?

Answer (score 3):

No.

Numbers are just numbers. They don't have formatting.

If you want formatting, use a string.